# Sort an array, nearlly done, just need to reset the minimum

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, variables, reset

I got το code an array sort for exam preparing. I am already done, the only prob is that my minimum variable is not resetting it self. And I can't put it "null"

Maybe you got an idea... In the beginning I put `min = c[0][0];` But if this is the smallest number. It won't work. :/

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {3,2,-1,-2,-5,4};
        specialSort(a);
    }

    static void specialSort(int[] a) {
        try {
            int[] b = new int[a.length];
            int[][] c = new int[a.length][2];

            for (int k = 0; k<a.length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l<2; l++) {
                    if (l == 0) {
                        c[k][l] = a[k];
                    } else {
                        c[k][l] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            int min, minindex;

            for (int j=0; j<c.length; j++) {
                for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
                    if (c[i][1] == 0) {
                        min = c[i][0];
                        if (min > c[i][0]) {
                            min=c[i][0];
                            minindex = i;
                        }
                    }
                } 
                b[j] = min;
                c[minindex][1] = 1;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<c.length; ++i) {
                //for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
                    System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("dulli");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A java tag is there, isn't it?

Comment: have you heard of these algorithms: selection sort, insertion sort?

Comment: Yes I do, mergesort, quicksort as well. But I am only allowed to use this one function, no new class or other imports...

Comment: it would best to comment your posted code so that you can explain to others how you want your customized sort algorithm to work.

Comment: you need to initialize minindex as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're saying and what your problem is, why don't you try setting min initially to

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

or

```
Long.MAX_VALUE
```

depending on the type of your data, so that you will replace it somehow with one of the numbers from your input, because for sure some number from your input will be smaller than the largest number java can represent? I think it should work if you do it this way